# What is a custom panel and how do you use it in stats.js?

Tags: javascript, statistics, customization, panel

Stats.js often says something about a 3+ panel support for custom panels. What do they mean for custom panel and how do you use it? I searched through many wikis and found no answer. Stats.js is a Javascript library that allows you to easily embed a performance monitor on your website. Here is the [Github Repository](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed no one was able to answer this question, so I just figured it out myself. The `addPanel()` allows you to pass in one argument to add in a panel into the performance monitor. It is a panel object. The syntax to create a panel object is:

```js
var panel = new Stats.Panel("name", "color1", "color2");
```

Using this method you can add in a panel as the following:

```js
var panelVar = addPanel( new Stats.Panel( 'name', 'color1', 'color2' ) );
```

Here is an example:

```js
var fpsPanel = addPanel( new Stats.Panel( 'FPS', '#0ff', '#002' ) );
```

Next, configuring the panel to show what it wants to show, you have to add-in a your code that configures the panel each frame. To do this you have to run your code in the format `panelVar.update(a, b)` where a is the amount in the top of the ratio and b is in the bottom. a / b will give the percentage that was shown. You have to run this code between `stats.begin()` and `stats.end()` inside the animation frame function.